# When I call api then redux does not wait for the response from api call and calls failure case even before getting response

Tags: react-native, redux, axios, redux-thunk

## ApiCall.js

Here I have called my API using Axios. I have used Promise to get the response. This response is resolved afterward and redux action calls failure case before getting this response.

```js
export const callPostApi = async (url, body) => {
  console.log('url ==> ', url, ' body ===> ', body);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      axios.post(url, body, config).then(
        (response) => {
          console.log('response ==> ', response.data);
          const { success, data, message } = response.data;
          if (!success) {
            alert(message);
          }
          return resolve(response.data);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.log('error in post api', error);
          return reject(error);
        }
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('error', error);
    }
  });
};

export const callLoginApi = async (body) => {
  const resp = await callPostApi(apis.LOGIN_URL, body);
  return resp;
};
```

## ActionCreator.js

```js
export const loginLoading = () => {
  return { type: types.LOGIN_LOADING };
};

export const loginSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: types.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
};

export const loginError = (error) => {
  return { type: types.LOGIN_ERROR, error };
};
```

## action.js

I am putting here async-await. But redux is not waiting for a response.
Here I am getting resp undefined after that API call response is received as successful.
what mistake am I making?

```
export const login = (body) => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(ActionCreator.loginLoading());
  try {
    const resp = await callLoginApi(body);
    console.log('login resp ==> ', resp);

    if (resp != undefined && resp != null) {
      const { success = false, message = '', data } = resp;

      if (success == true) {
        const obj = { user: data.user, token: data.token, isLoggedIn: true };
        dispatch(ActionCreator.loginSuccess(obj));
        storeJSON(CONST.user, data.user);
        storeString(CONST.token, data.token);
        RootNavigation.navigate(SCREENS.Tab, { screen: SCREENS.Home });
      } else {
        dispatch(ActionCreator.loginError(message));
      }
      if (message != '') {
        alert(message);
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch(ActionCreator.loginError(error));
  }
};
```

Comment: To perform async actions use thunk middleware https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk

Comment: @MichaelBahl I am already using redux-thunk

Comment: As callPostApi is async is it necessary to return a promise?
Try to remove the async before callPostApi.